# Junit for Consumer class returning lambda

Tags: java, lambda, junit, consumer

I am writing junit test case for below for consumer class which has below method.

```java
@Bean 
@Transactional 
public Consumer<Message<String>> response() {  
    return message -> { 
        Acknowledgment ack = message.getHeaders().get(Ack, Acknowledgment.class);
        helper(message); 
        log.info("hello"); 
        ack.acknowlege(); 
    }
```

I am trying to go inside the lambda function through test method but able to proceed further. I tried to write the test as below:

```java
@Test
public void testHelper() {
    Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload("Hello").build();
    consumer.response();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are referencing `java.util.function.Consumer`, the `response` method is at present returning an instance of the `Consumer` type and is not invoking the implementation as shared.

The operations would be performed only once you call the [`accept`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Consumer.html#accept(T)) method of the Consumer returned. Thereafter you can [`verify`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#4) the occurrences of the methods invoked within.

Comment: Naman, can you please elaborate a bit. I am new to junit test case.